# Jquery Validate, should be eager validating but it isn't

Tags: jquery, validation

I am running the ever popular: Jquery Validate: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

```
$("#lo-form").validate();
```

Its pretty straight forward.  However if a form is submited with invalid fields it highlights them and should remove the highlight and error message once a given field is resolved.  From my reading this is called Eager Validation.

In this case however if I fix an invalid field, it leaves the message displayed.

http://settlementprep.com/pre-qual/homeowner/

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing some code on some of your form fields.

If you submit the form and start typing in the email field, the Eager Validation works because you've set it to have a `type="email"`.

However, on the 'first name' field, you need to add `type="text"` and then a validation parameter, for example, `minlength="2"`.

If you change that on the 'first name' field, you should see the Eager Validation kicking in. Just rinse and repeat for the rest of your form fields based on the required validation.

Comment: Cool I'll try that and report bacl

Comment: thanks. apparently a type="text" is required for eager validation.